# How to get sum value from start time and end time?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a start time, duration and a data value in Columns A, B and C respectively.

**How can I capture the data that falls during the start time and end time and insert the sum of this data in a 30-minute cycle (e.g. 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30 etc) in the "Output" column?**

For example, if Data_A had a start time was at 09:15 and end time at 10:15, its value would be returned at 09:00, 09:30 and 10:00.

If more than 1 data value was received within the same 30-minute cycle, the values would be summed.
For example, Data_A has a value of 0.1 and Data_B has a value of 0.2.
Data_B has a start time at 09:50 and end time at 10:10. The sum values at 09:00, 09:30 and 10:00 would be 0.1, 0.3 and 0.3 respectively.

If no data was received for any 30-minute cycle, it simply returns a zero.

The following `SUMIFS` function can be used to sum the values at start time but I couldn't modify it to take into account the duration and end time.

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,">="&G2,$A$2:$A$10,"<"&G2+TIME(0,29,59))
```

The dataset I have is over a year's worth, I am open to solutions using cell equations or VBA.

[Link to dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjwakhssnwgbmsy/Book1.xlsx?dl=0)

[image: excel]

Comment: Can you better explain why 28/07/2021 9:30 would return 0.2 and 10:00 returns 0?

Comment: @P.b That was a mistake, thank you for noticing. I've updated the image and file.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for? The conditional sum? In that case, what do you expect that your formula doesn't give you?

Comment: @P.b Updated the image and file. The formula currently gives the sum value only on the start date. I can use it to calculate the sum value on the end date. But not sure how to sum values that lie between the start and end dates for the half-hour intervals in the Datetime column.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the end time inclusion/exclusion correctly, but how about `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,"<"&$G2+TIME(0,30,0),$E$2:$E$10,">="&$G2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a VBA function `SumBetweenDateTimeLoop` with inputs the cell of the starting datetime, the range of starting time, range of ending time, range of values to add and minutes of the loop (in this case fixed to `30`).

```
Public Function SumBetweenDateTimeLoop(this_date As Range, dt_start As Range, dt_end As Range, values As Range, min_loop As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim v As Double
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    Dim v1 As Date, v2 As Date
    
    If dt_start.Count <> dt_end.Count Or values.Count <> dt_end.Count Or dt_start.Count <> values.Count Then
        Call MsgBox("Length of ranges have to be the same.")
        Exit Function
    End If

    v = 0
    For i = 1 To dt_start.Count
        d1 = CDate(dt_start(i))
        d2 = CDate(dt_end(i))
        v1 = CDate(this_date)
        v2 = DateAdd("n", min_loop, v1)

        If Not ((d1 < v1 And d2 < v1) Or (d1 > v2 And d2 > v2)) Then
            v = v + CDbl(values(i))
        End If
    Next i
    
    SumBetweenDateTimeLoop = v

End Function
```

The result is reported in the red column (there are some differences from your green column but it should be correct if I understood correctly your problem).
[image]

In order to call the function (after have copied it into a module in VBA), type in the desired Excel cell the following request.

```
=SumBetweenDateTimeLoop(G2;A$2:A$10;E$2:E$10;C$2:C$10;30)
```

### Code explanation

The idea is to define extremes of the cycle, so define `v1` as the datetime in column `G` and `v2 = v1+min_loop`.

Then make a loop over the cells of the ranges (Excel columns `A`, `E` and `C`), define the extremes of datetime (`d1` start datetime in column `A` and `d2` ending datetime in column `E`) and check whether or not both `d1` and `d2` are lower than `v1` or greather than `v2`.
If this condition is not satisfied, it means that at least a part of the time is inside the desired cycle and then add the relative value to the incremental parameter `v`, which at the end will be the return of the function.

Comment: Differences between green and red columns are because dates change (there are `29/07` and `30/07`), information not cosidered in the green column of "expected output". I wondering then if I understood correctly or not the task. In fact, in `30/07/2021 12:00` the expected output should be zero, it is correct 0.9 if referred to the previous day instead.

Comment: I encountered the same. I'm also missing some datetime values that would seem logic to me.

Comment: @Stefø I think your results are correct, I noticed I made a mistake. For some reason I cannot get your VBA code to work, I am adding it as a module and calling it in column M as you have shown. Perhaps the code is not compatible with Office 365?

Comment: @jim: what kind of error did you encounter? Is it on VBA script or just in the Excel cell? If the second, try replacing `;` with `,`. Anyway the cell in which you call it doesn't matter and I don't think the code could be not compatible with Office 365.

Comment: @Stefø No error, when I copy the formula to the cells, all the values are 0. I replaced `;` with `,`.

Comment: @Stefø Would it be possible for you to share the excel file you used please? I'm sure the issue is on my end, I have another computer with Excel 2017 which I always found to be better.

Comment: @jim : I found a copy-paste error in the code proposed, now fixed in the answer. Just change the penultime line with `SumBetweenDateTimeLoop = v`. If it still not work, I'll try to upload the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult: the solution is 48 :-)

By this I mean that, in Excel, and entire day is one unit (e.g. `01/01/2022 + 1 = 02/01/2022`).
As a result, one hour equals 1/24th and half an hour (30 minutes) corresponds with 1/48th of a day.

So, you want to round down to 1/48, which you can do using this simple formula:

```
=FLOOR(B2*48,1)/48
```

Hereby some examples:

[image]

Comment: Not really an answer to the question asked, but helpful

Comment: @P.b: my answer gives a starting point of this part of question: "For example, if Data_A had a start time was at 09:15 and end time at 10:15, its value would be returned at 09:00, 09:30 and 10:00.".

Comment: Understood and helpful, but more like a comment